# How do I import my KDE Konsole color scheme to iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, unix, iterm, file-conversion, themes

I've spent many moons adjusting my default Konsole color scheme in KDE, and I would like to use it in iTerm2 on my Macbook Pro.

I have the Konsole color scheme file `ardnew.colorscheme`, and I currently only have desktop access to my Macbook (KDE access is ssh-only).

I can't seem to figure out the name of the particular format used in `.colorscheme` files, but iTerm2 refused to recognize it as a supported format when I tried to import it directly. The file icon is grayed out.

Is there a tool or script or site I can use (from macOS) to convert this file to something iTerm2 recognizes?

Otherwise, when I get home tonight, I will have access to my KDE desktop again. In that case, same question - how can I convert this bad boy from a KDE context? (Perhaps I'm at the wrong SE site in this case)

---

Below are examples for both formats, Konsole and iTerm2:

###### Konsole `*.colorscheme`

```
[Background]
Color=19,20,21

[BackgroundFaint]
Color=30,30,30

[BackgroundIntense]
Color=19,20,21

[Color0]
Color=164,193,202

[Color0Faint]
Color=164,193,202

[Color0Intense]
Color=201,237,247

[Color1]
Color=249,38,114

[Color1Faint]
Color=249,38,114

[Color1Intense]
Color=255,89,149

[Color2]
Color=130,180,20

[Color2Faint]
Color=130,180,20

[Color2Intense]
Color=182,227,84

[Color3]
Color=253,151,31

[Color3Faint]
Color=253,151,31

[Color3Intense]
Color=254,237,108

[Color4]
Color=78,130,170

[Color4Faint]
Color=78,130,170

[Color4Intense]
Color=12,115,194

[Color5]
Color=140,84,254

[Color5Faint]
Color=140,84,254

[Color5Intense]
Color=158,111,254

[Color6]
Color=94,113,116

[Color6Faint]
Color=94,113,116

[Color6Intense]
Color=76,107,108

[Color7]
Color=204,204,198

[Color7Faint]
Color=204,204,198

[Color7Intense]
Color=248,248,242

[Foreground]
Color=219,228,237

[ForegroundFaint]
Color=219,228,237

[ForegroundIntense]
Color=255,255,255

[General]
Blur=true
ColorRandomization=false
Description=ardnew
Opacity=0.88
Wallpaper=
```

###### iTerm2 `*.itermcolors`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Ansi 0 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.17263323068618774</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.17263594269752502</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.17263087630271912</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 1 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.51764309406280518</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.15650489926338196</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.81688457727432251</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 10 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.74065512418746948</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.86353534460067749</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.42949733138084412</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 11 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.23970609903335571</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.90355896949768066</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.96323567628860474</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 12 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.99169284105300903</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.78264778852462769</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.10320568829774857</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 13 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.89684361219406128</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.43724477291107178</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.48607546091079712</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 14 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.83805406093597412</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.76803940534591675</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.36635768413543701</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 15 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.95626014471054077</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.9562721848487854</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.9562498927116394</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 2 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.5445636510848999</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.70215117931365967</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 3 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.092118002474308014</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.6658928394317627</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.71714216470718384</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 4 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.81191211938858032</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.62685704231262207</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 5 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.54865092039108276</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.31547874212265015</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.39789503812789917</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 6 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.77837508916854858</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.70279031991958618</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.11805730313062668</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 7 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.8797488808631897</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.87975996732711792</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.87973928451538086</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 8 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.32783189415931702</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.32783645391464233</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.32782799005508423</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 9 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.55107885599136353</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.18106639385223389</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.99860554933547974</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Background Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.17263323068618774</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.17263594269752502</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.17263087630271912</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Badge Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>0.5</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.1491314172744751</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Bold Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.55107885599136353</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.18106639385223389</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.99860554933547974</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Cursor Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.99169284105300903</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.78264778852462769</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.10320568829774857</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Cursor Guide Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>0.1431884765625</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.57059025764465332</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.58319091796875</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Cursor Text Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.95626014471054077</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.9562721848487854</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.9562498927116394</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Foreground Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.95626014471054077</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.9562721848487854</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.9562498927116394</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Link Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.73423302173614502</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.35916060209274292</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Selected Text Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.95626014471054077</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.9562721848487854</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.9562498927116394</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Selection Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.99430257081985474</real>
        <key>Color Space</key>
        <string>sRGB</string>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.87257224321365356</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.7615014910697937</real>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are Konsole and iTerm2 both use text files for the color scheme? How do they look like, can you add samples?

Comment: @nohillside added file format examples

Comment: http://terminal.sexy/ allows conversions, but doesn't seem to support Konsole as input.

Comment: <shrug> Take the color values, type them into the same fields in iTerm's preferences dialog, save.  No reason to agonize over it.